# Responsive CSS with Twitter Bootstrap Issue

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a NavBar in my web-app using Ruby on Rails and Twitter Bootstrap.

The NAVBAR looks well in the browser as:
[image: NAVBAR in the browser]

But, the Navbar breaks when I look up the web-app in the browser on my Galaxy Note.

[image: NAVBAR broken in smaller screen]
*Snippet from app/views/layouts/application.html.erb*

```
  <div class="masthead">
    <h3 class="active"><a href="/">WebsiteName</a></h3>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>

            <% if current_user %>
              <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                      <strong><%= current_user.name %></strong>
                      <b class="caret"></b>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="/signout">Sign out</a></li>
                  </ul>
            <% end %>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**The CSS for the NAVBAR** is borrowed primarily from:
Justified Nav Example - http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/justified-nav.html

```
  /* Customize the navbar links to be fill the entire space of the .navbar */
  .navbar .navbar-inner {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar .nav {
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar .nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar .nav li a {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  }
  .navbar .nav li:first-child a {
    border-left: 0;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  }
  .navbar .nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  }
```

How can I fix this? I am learning Responsive CSS these days, and have no idea how to fix it.

**UPDATE:**

Please note that the above problem has been fixed.
But I found something wrong when this got fixed though. If I decrease the size of window too much, the navbar gets broken. The User part goes outside the navbar. **The issue is also reflected in the Bootstrap example too**.

I'm attaching the screenshots which showcase the issue. To see it yourself, simply decrease the window size in the [Bootstrap navbar example](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/justified-nav.html).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your `User` button element looks very different from rest. You are not closing the list element immediately below `<% if current_user %>`

Comment: Thanks @user568109, but edsioufi found the missing nowrap element and it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is that the "Contact Us" link is wrapping.** Notice that, in the [Bootstrap example](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/justified-nav.html), the navbar does not have links with multiple words.

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to the `.navbar .nav li a` class.

Here is a functioning [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bsJgR/2/). All you have to do is resize the width of the frame to test.

The demo contains 2 navbars:

- The first navbar with the issue fixed.
- The second reproduces the faulty behavior to isolate the cause at the "Contact us" link, by setting its `style` attribute to `"white-space: normal;"` thus overriding the fix.

**Also note** that you have a `</li>` missing before `<% end %>`.

Comment: I found something wrong when this got fixed though. If I decrease the size of window too much in the Jsfiddle, the correct navbar above gets broken. The User part goes outside the navbar. The issue is also reflected in the Bootstrap example too. I have updated the question to reflect my findings.

Answer (score 0):

define the heihgt of `.navbar .nav`  40px and add `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

Your bootstrap file loading should look like the following to make the responsive work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
```

Comment: In my `app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` file, I have `@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive"; `. Then after these 2 lines, I have ` <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`.

So, my order is different that what you have suggested. Does it matter?

Comment: No.Just the place of the two css files is important.It doesnt matter that where is the meta tag.

Comment: In that case, the place is correct. But, the design is not responsive.